# Tornar widget do facebook responsivo

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma div que é colocado noticias, e na laterial desta div, tem o widget do facebook, queria que o tamanho dele fosse responsivo, ou seja, a altura dele fosse a mesma que a div de noticia

Meu html atual:

```
 <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12" id="noticias">
        <h3 class="">Ultimas Notícias</h3>
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-3"
                     style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[0]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                        <div class="card-title mb-1">
                            <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[0]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                            <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[0]['titulo'] ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text ">
                            <?php echo $noticias[0]['mensagem'] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-3"
                     style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[1]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                        <div class="card-title mb-1">
                            <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[1]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                            <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[1]['titulo'] ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text ">
                            <?php echo $noticias[1]['mensagem'] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-3"
                     style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[2]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                        <div class="card-title mb-1">
                            <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[2]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                            <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[2]['titulo'] ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text ">
                            <?php echo $noticias[2]['mensagem'] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" ml-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div>    </div>
</div>
```

Resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Igor Essa div está fazendo o que no HTML? <div id="fb-root"></div> Você poderia colocar o CSS também?

Comment: esta div faz parte do código padrão do widget, apenas copiei do fb, ele n acrescenta nada em css

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Igor

Entendi. Acredito que basicamente seja a estrutura do código, acho que utilizou o Bootstrap como framework.

Eu criei a partir do Bootstrap a nova estrutura, deixei comentado no código, você pode apagar se quiser, substituí algumas colunas, peço para que olhe o código PHP, pois posso ter deixado algo escapar e teste essa estrutura:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Você pode alterar o container-fluid apenas para container -->
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <!-- Titulo Notícias -->
     <div  id="noticias" class="col-md-10">
        <h3> Ultimas Notícias </h3>
     </div>
     <!-- Início das notícias -->

     <!-- N0 -->
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <!-- Imagem 
                col-3
            -->
            <div class="col-md-3"
                 style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[0]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
            <!-- Dados da Notícia
                col-9
             -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                    <div class="card-title mb-1">
                        <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[0]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                        <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[0]['titulo'] ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text ">
                        <?php echo $noticias[0]['mensagem'] ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--FIM  Dados da Notícia -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- N1 -->
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <!-- Imagem 
                col-3
            -->
            <div class="col-md-3"
                 style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[1]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
            <!-- Dados da Notícia
                col-9
             -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                    <div class="card-title mb-1">
                        <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[1]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                        <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[1]['titulo'] ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text ">
                        <?php echo $noticias[1]['mensagem'] ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--FIM  Dados da Notícia -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- N2 -->
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <!-- Imagem 
                col-3
            -->
            <div class="col-md-3"
                 style="background:url(<?php echo $noticias[2]['imagem'] ?>) center;background-size: cover !important"></div>
            <!-- Dados da Notícia
                col-9
             -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="card-block mx-2 my-1">
                    <div class="card-title mb-1">
                        <div class="text-muted float-right"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($noticias[2]['dataenvio'])) ?></div>
                        <div class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $noticias[2]['titulo'] ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text ">
                        <?php echo $noticias[2]['mensagem'] ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--FIM  Dados da Notícia -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Segunda Coluna -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Facebook -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}
                (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
            <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Testei e a estrutura ficou bacana, mas como não tenho o php, não consegui visualizar com as notícias.

Comment: não funcionou, continua com um tamanho fixo

Comment: Adicione essa classe no seu css `class="fb-page"` e adicione `padding-top: 1em;`